# Inputting Printing an Array From One Class To Another Java (Like a Sign Up Array)

Tags: java, arrays

How can I insert any value from here:

```
package main;
import java.util.*;
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        int count=0;
        boolean again=true;
        signup sign = new signup();
        count++;
        while(again) {
        System.out.println("Enter username: ");
        sign.user[count]=scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter password: ");
        sign.pass[count]=scan.next();

            System.out.print("Sign up? [Y/N] : ");
            String a = scan.next();
            
                if (a.equals("Y")&&sign.user[count]!=null&&sign.pass[count]!=null) {
                    System.out.println("[1]Back to log-in\n[2]View Accounts");
                    int b = scan.nextInt();
                        switch (b) {
                        case 1: 
                            login newlog = new login();
                            newlog.loginhere();
                        ;
                        case 2:
                            accounts newaccs = new accounts();
                            newaccs.accountshere();
                        ;
                        }
                } else if(a.equals("Y")&&sign.user[count]!=null&&sign.pass[count]==null){
                    System.out.println("Please fill out a password field!");
                    again=true;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

to here:

```
package login;
public class signup {

    String [] user = new String [100];
    String [] pass = new String [100];
    public void username (String user[],String pass[]) {
        this.user=user;
        this.pass=pass;
    }
    public String[] re() {
        return user;
    }
    public String[] res() {
        return pass;
    }
}
```

and then whenever I select sign up from my main method and select view accounts, I want all the stored value from my second class to be printed here in my third class:

```
package login;

    public class accounts {
        
        public void accountshere() {
            signup sign = new signup();
            System.out.println("Username\tPassword");
            for(int i=0; i<=1;i++)
            System.out.println(sign.user+"\t"+sign.pass);
        }
    }
```

I hope you guys can help me, I don't know what am I doing to be honest, and I know I'm messing up, I just want to learn new things in programming. Feel free to criticize my code and correct me in a good manner. And I hope you guys get the point of my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: you can pass parameters to your methods, I would recommend first learn about the value of setters and getters, decent use of access modifiers and naming conventions.

Comment: and I hope you guys can explain me how the solution in my problem works :>